# Wordpress Event Between dates

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, date

Good morning everyone,

Im working on an events list, using wordpress and custom fields. I am able to get upcoming events with my current query. 
My issues comes when an event that is current however the start date is before the current date.

For example. If today's date is June 26, 2014 and I have an event that started June 25, 2014 and ends July 1, 2014 the current query would see the event as passed.

How can i modify this query to keep events that are still currently going? 
My event date variables are event_start_date and event_end_date

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'page_type',
            'value' => 'Event',
        ), 
        array(
            'key' => 'event_start_date',
            'value' => date('Ymd'),
            'compare' => '>='
        )
    ),
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key'=> 'event_start_date',
 );

$upcoming_event = get_posts($args);
```

Comment: You need to query on `event_end_date` and sort on `event_start_date` to get the result you want. You'll also need to make sure that every event has both an end date and start date specified. If you can't you'll need to write your own query with SQL to deal with all your edge cases.

Comment: Each event will have an end date, but is there no way to write a query that says something like: if date range is within threshold of current time?

Comment: You can, but you're limited in the way you can do this with Wordpress meta queries. If you can't come up with a series of simple comparisons which can either all be combined with an `AND` or `OR`, you need to delve into writing your own with SQL.